# How to call a method on one running thread but execute it on another running thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, java-threads

I am new to java threads. I have an client application that is running on 2 threads: `WorkerThread` and `JavaFxGuiThread`. My question is: can i call a method on `GuiThread` (on press of a button) but execute it on `WorkerThread`? Note that that at the time when i call method and execute it both threads are already doing other stuff.
Here is the sample of my code:

```
class WorkerThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        searchForConnections(); // <-- should run at the start of a thread
        
        // should wait for onButtonPressed() and only then execute
        // sendMessage() on WorkerThread, not on GuiThread
    }
    private String searchForConnections() {
        // constantly searches for connections
        return connection;
    }
    private void sendMessage() {
        //sends message
        System.out.println("message sent!");
    }
}
class GuiThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runGui(); // <-- should run at the start of a thread
        
        // waits until user press the button
        // and only then:
        onButtonPressed();
    }
    private void onButtonPressed() {
        // should somehow run sendMessage() inside
        // WorkerThread run() method
        // ( which should run sendMessage() on WorkerThread not GuiThread )
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new WorkerThread()).start();  // starts GuiThread run() method
        new Thread(new GuiThread()).start();     // starts WorkerThread run() method
    }
}
```

I want to avoid calling `sendMessage()` on `GuiThread`.

Similar answers here only show how to run methods AT THE START of a thread while i believe that my situation is different because threads are already running.

Comment: Short answer is no - or at least not the way you might be thinking - the longer as is, you could use a Runnable which could have your other threads “run”, much like a queue of tasks, just as an example

Comment: This just isn’t how GUI frameworks work (at least, any I’ve worked with, including JavaFX). They are *event driven*. Just register an event handler with the button and it will be invoked when the button is pressed. The UI thread is already implemented for you, running (transparently; you never even need to be aware of it) a loop for you which waits for user events to happe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you've got a slight conceptual misunderstanding. Don't think about how to call a method from one thread and have it execute on a different thread. Instead, think about how to pass objects between threads. You want to give your "worker thread" a message to send. So, you need to figure out how to give that message *object* to said thread.

Essentially, you need to provide a "synchronization point" where you can pass data (or even actions, e.g., as `Runnable`s<sup>**1**</sup>) between threads. There are quite a few ways you can do this. And how exactly you decide to do this depends on how exactly this "worker thread" of yours is supposed to work. Regardless, I recommend doing some research into Java concurrency. Take a look at:

- Concurrency tutorials (e.g., [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) or [this one](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-concurrency/index.html), among many others, including full books).
- The `synchronized` keyword and the corresponding `wait`, `notify`, and `notifyAll` methods (all declared in `Object`).
- The [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html), [`java.util.concurrent.atomic`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html), and [`java.util.concurrent.locks`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html) packages.
- [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm#JFXIP546) and the [`javafx.concurrent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/package-summary.html) package (both JavaFX-specific; you included the [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx) tag).

Concurrency is hard, and it's going to take some work to become proficient with it.

That said, if your "worker thread" is meant to send multiple messages as the user enters them, then probably one of the easiest solutions is to use a [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). Here's an example (in JavaFX, given the [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx) tag):

```java
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  private ExecutorService executor;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    BlockingQueue<String> messageQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);
    executor.execute(new Messenger(messageQueue));

    TextField inputField = new TextField();

    Button sendBtn = new Button("Send");
    sendBtn.setDefaultButton(true);
    sendBtn.setOnAction(e -> {
      e.consume();

      String message = inputField.getText();
      if (message != null && !message.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.printf(
            "[%s] Enqueueing message: '%s'%n",
            Thread.currentThread().getName(),
            message  
        );
        messageQueue.add(message);
        inputField.clear();
      }
    });

    HBox root = new HBox(10, inputField, sendBtn);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    HBox.setHgrow(inputField, Priority.ALWAYS);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, -1));
    primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Demo");
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  @Override
  public void stop() {
    executor.shutdownNow();
  }

  private static class Messenger implements Runnable {

    private final BlockingQueue<String> queue;

    Messenger(BlockingQueue<String> queue) {
      this.queue = Objects.requireNonNull(queue, "queue");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        searchForConnections();
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
          String message = queue.take();
          sendMessage(message);
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
        // If the thread is interrupted, we simply want to stop
      }
    }

    private void searchForConnections() {}

    private void sendMessage(String message) {
      System.out.printf(
          "[%s] Sending message: '%s'%n",
          Thread.currentThread().getName(),
          message
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Note how this actually works. We aren't calling a method from one thread, but having it execute on another. We have the background thread (your "worker thread") blocked on the `BlockingQueue` waiting for messages to send. When the *JavaFX Application Thread* (the UI thread) places a `String` in the queue, the background thread takes it and calls `sendMessage` with the `String`.

Also, in case there's some confusion here, note how we do not create nor manage the UI thread. That is handled by the UI framework, and the thread is already running in essentially a loop that processes user-generated events and syncs the rendered UI with the state of the scene graph.

If you run the above example, type `Hello, World!` into the text field, and then trigger the <kbd>Send</kbd> button, you should see something like:

```
[JavaFX Application Thread] Enqueueing message: 'Hello, World!'
[pool-2-thread-1] Sending message: 'Hello, World!'
```

Printed to the console.

---

<sup>**1.** One of the main `ExecutorService` implementations, `ThreadPoolExecutor`, works on this principle. It maintains a `BlockingQueue<Runnable>` and a pool of threads. These threads essentially loop trying to take a `Runnable` from the queue and then calling its `run()` method. The queue is populated by calling e.g., `execute` and `submit` on the `ExecutorService`. And that's one way you can give a "task" to another thread. It's also how the above example executes `Messenger` on a background thread.</sup>